Working with errno in a cross-platform way in .NET
I am writing a cross-platform .NET library which relies on P/Invoke into system libraries. I need to handle errors which invoked functions report through the errno variable. This variable can be accessed via Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() on Unix. Then I need to compare the error with error codes defined by the POSIX errno.h header and throw a specific exception with corresponding error message.
There are two problems:

POSIX does not define numeric values for specific errors, requiring to use the macros from errno.h. The values indeed differ for different Unixes, e.g. Linux and Mac OS X.
The preferred way to get the error message is the strerror_r function, but on Linux this function could be defined as either int strerror_r(int errnum, char buf[.buflen], size_t buflen); or char *strerror_r(int errnum, char buf[.buflen], size_t buflen);. It is expected to test for a macro to determine which one to use.

I looked into .NET and Mono sources to find how is is handled there and found that both runtimes define native functions to return abstracted error codes from errno and to get error messages, so all the macros are resolved at compile time. I want to avoid distributing a native library (how many versions of it could be ever needed?) and solve the problem with just managed code. Is this even possible to do reliably?
